# how to access a file placed outside karaf in karaf bundle

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

i have a file **check** placed at /home/abc. I want to read this file from a bundle running in karaf.

Location of that file is fixed. So, i can hardcode that. But i am not able to find a way for it.

Answer (score 0):

one way- you need to copy the file into the /etc/ folder.
second way- you need to define JAVA_OPTS=-DprojectName="/directorypath/filename" into the /bin/karaf.bat or .sh file and restart the karaf.

write the code like this you are reading the file from

`String s= System.getPropety("projectName/filename");
 File f = new File(s);`